# How to translate background using -moz-repeating-linear-gradient to -webkit (specific example)

Tags: webkit, css, linear-gradients

I did this background in firefox but I can't replicate it in webkit/chrome (I have tried several alternatives but nothing):

```
background: -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, gray, transparent 1px, transparent 5px) repeat scroll 0 0 white;
```

What would be the correct translation? It is possible to achieve the same pattern? (or at least a very close one).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh! It was there in the documentation! :

http://www.webkit.org/blog/175/introducing-css-gradients/

> If you want to achieve effects like
>   tiling of a vertical gradient using a
>   narrow strip, you should specify
>   background-size to give the gradient
>   tile an explicit size.

So it was fixed adding:

```
background-size: 10px;
```

Gecko and Webkit acts differently in this matter: While Gecko will adjust the background size automatically if you specify the gradient steps in "px", webkit will (possibly) calculate the % based in the "px" measure you set.

I'm not sure if my English is correct, but that is the idea...

Answer (score 0):

`-webkit-repeating-greadient(...)` :)

Supported by Chrome and Webkit nightlies.

Comment: `left top 0deg` is not a correct angle, it was dropped from the spec (for easier parsing I think). You need to pick one of the two, either `left top` or `0deg`. I'm guessing you actually want `top` or `0deg` (they're equivalent).

Comment: Yes... For some reason I ended up mixing it... I will correct it. Thank you for pointing it out and for trying to help in the first place.